# Determine wether the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sin \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is defferentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $D=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\pi\}$.
> Define $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> 0,  & \text{if $x= 0$ } \\
> \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sin \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, & \text{if $x\in D-(0,0)$}
> \end{cases}$. Is $f$ différentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

I have computed $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=1$. I'm stuck at $$\lim \limits_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{h^2+k^2}{\sin \sqrt{h^2+k^2}}-h-k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Did you try using increment theorem?

Comment: The function $f$ is not well-defined. For example, what is $f(0,0.1)$? The conditions on the first line and the second line are both satisfied. However, under the first condition, $f(0,0.1)=0$, while under the second condition, $f(0,0.1)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see if $f$ is partially derivable w.r.t. $x$ at $(0,0)$. Since
$$
\frac{f(x, 0) - f(0,0)}{x}
= \frac{|x|}{x} \cdot \frac{|x|}{\sin |x|}\,,
$$
we conclude that the limit as $x\to 0$ of the above quantity does not exist.

Comment: I thought it was $\frac{x}{\sin |x|}$, how can I show that this limit does not exist?

Comment: Compute the right and left limits as $x\to 0$ (they are different).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake computing the partial derivatives, they actually don't exist at the origin. For example, if you set $y$ to zero, and use the approximation $\sin x = x$ near the origin, you can see that your function reduces to $|x|$, which is not differentiable.